# How to perform a sequence of a very large image averaging in python / OpenCV?

Tags: python, performance, image-processing, numpy, out-of-memory

I'm working with TIFF-images of 30,000 x 30,000 pixels, and want to average 11 of these images at once.

I'd prefer to do it in python if possible, and was wondering what's the best way to approach this?

Should I use `OpenCV` or can it be done just using `numpy`?

Will averaging each of RGBA channels independently improve performance?

Or should I divide the images into smaller images and process them independently, and then stitch the resulting pieces back together?

Doing it straight-up with openCV like this leads to memory errors:

```
im0 = cv2.imread( '5014.tif' )
im1 = cv2.imread( '5114.tif' )
im2 = cv2.imread( '5214.tif' )
im3 = cv2.imread( '5314.tif' )
im4 = cv2.imread( '5414.tif' )
cv2.imwrite( 'avg.tif', .01*im0 -.002*im1 -.002*im2 -.002*im3 -.002*im4 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "stack" has the "shape" `(30000, 30000, 4, 11)`.  I wouldn't worry about manually looping over these last two dimensions in any way - I would worry about running out of memory as you are experiencing.

I don't know the OpenCV syntax but if you can read in one image without memory issues do something like:

```
image_filenames = ['5014.tif', '5114.tif', ...]
N = float(len(image_filenames))

output = # empty array of image dimensions

for image_filename in image_filenames:
    # read in this image
    # add image / N to output

# save the output
```

Comment: With due respect, the Memory Footprint is 12x (not 11x) and the averaging does not use arithmetic mean, but a different calculus.

Answer (score 4):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) is an image processing system for large images. It streams images rather than doing separate load / process / save steps, so you can work with images much larger than the amount of memory in your computer. It has a handy, [high-level python binding](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/). It should be [quicker than opencv](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use) for this sort of task.

You can solve your problem in Python like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyvips

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("usage: %s output-file in1 in2 ..." % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

outfile = sys.argv[1]
input_names = sys.argv[2:]

total = sum([pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access="sequential")
             for filename in input_names])
avg = total / len(input_names)

# avg will be a float image, cast back to 8-bit for write, or we'll 
# get a float tiff
avg.cast("uchar").write_to_file(outfile)
```

Run like this:

```
$ time ./avg.py x.tif ~/pics/wtc*.tif
memory: high-water mark 38.50 MB
real    0m5.759s
user    0m2.584s
sys 0m0.457s
```

That's averaging four 10,000 x 10,000 RGB images on a machine with a mechanical HDD, so I'd guess about two minutes for your dataset. Memory use should be around 100mb.

Answer (score 2):

### What performance to get improved?

1. **SMALLER** static **Memory Footprint** -- as processing **does not** perform any convoluted calculi, just change the processing scheme to get from 30GB static RAM footprint to some 5GB. ( code sample runs this way, iterating over the sequence of 11-files )

---

```
aListOfFNAMEs = [ ''5014.tif', ...                      ] # SETUP: FNAMEs
aListOfCOEFFs = [ .01, -.002, -.002, -.002, -.002, .... ] #        COEFFs till the 11-th

anInputIMG    = cv2.imread( aListOfFNAMEs[0] )            # LOAD
anAveragedIMG = numpy.zeros( anInputIMG.shape )           # ensure .copy, not view

anAveragedIMG += aListOfCOEFFs[0]*anInputIMG              # process the 1st LOAD-ed

for aPtr in range( 1, len(aListOfCOEFFs ) ):              # iterate, process the rest
    anInputIMG     = cv2.imread( aListOfFNAMEs[aPtr] )    #          re-use MEM on LOAD(s)
    anAveragedIMG += aListOfCOEFFs[aPtr] * anInputIMG     #          process <next>

cv2.imwrite( "avg.TIF", anAveragedIMG )                   # SAVE
del anInputIMG                                            # release for GC
del anAveragedIMG                                         # release for GC, DONE.
```

---

2. **FASTER** vectorised **Matrix Operations** -- as processing allows numpy/openCV vectorised matrix operations, RGB-colorplane separation into independent processing **does not** improve the speed, just the contrary. ( code above runs that way )
3. **FASTEST** GPU-based **Block Operations** -- while possible, would introduce your Project to spend remarkable time on arranging GPU-device / HOST-device data transfers, so as to be moving less data per Block, than the size of hte GPU-DRAM allows. The requested calculation has such a low mathematical/calculation-density, that it does not justify these overheads to move into GPU-based mode.

Comment: Thanks - I accepted the other answer bc it came in first but your additional explanation and code are much appreciated!!

Comment: Thanks - I actually didn't know I could do that for a question I asked.